# AreaCharts with CheckBoxes for each Serie on Javafx

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx

I have an AreaChart with some CheckBoxes to select which series would like to appear on the AreaChart. The problem is that I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added
```

This is the code that is executed when one of the 3 checkBoxes change his value.

```
   /**AreaChart<Integer,Double> multipleGraphic;
        * CheckBox HeartRateCheck,PedalingRateCheck,AverageSpeedCheck;
        * XYChart.Series AvSpeed = new XYChart.Series();
        * XYChart.Series Cadence = new XYChart.Series();
        * XYChart.Series HeartRate = new XYChart.Series();
        **/


    private void setMultiGraph() {

            multipleGraphic.getData().removeAll(multipleGraphic.getData());
            multipleGraphic.getData().clear();

            if (HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {
                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(AvSpeed, Cadence, HeartRate);
            }

            if (!HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {

                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(AvSpeed, Cadence);
            }
            if (HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && !PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {

                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(AvSpeed, HeartRate);
            }
            if (HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && !AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {

                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(Cadence, HeartRate);
            }

            if (!HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && !PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {

                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(AvSpeed);
            }
            if (!HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && !AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {

                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(Cadence);
            }
            if (HeartRateCheck.isSelected() && !PedalingRateCheck.isSelected() && !AverageSpeedCheck.isSelected()) {

                multipleGraphic.getData().addAll(HeartRate);
            }
        }
```

[Image of the AreaChart with the 3 CheckBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlIy6.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use checkbox selected property change listeners to add or remove a series from the graph as appropriate.

```
private void addSeriesListener(BooleanProperty selected, final XYChart.Series series) {
    selected.addListener((observable, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
        if (isSelected) {
            chart.getData().add(series);
        } else {
            chart.getData().remove(series);
        }
    });
}
. . .
addSeriesListener(heartRateCheck.selectedProperty(), heartRateSeries);
addSeriesListener(cadenceCheck.selectedProperty(), cadenceSeries);
addSeriesListener(speedCheck.selectedProperty(), speedSeries);
```

[image: sampleapppicture]

*Full Sample App*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class AreaChartSample extends Application {
    private static final String HEART_RATE = "Heart Rate";
    private static final String PEDALING_RATE = "Pedaling Rate";
    private static final String AVERAGE_SPEED = "Average Speed";

    private Random random = new Random(42);

    private NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    private NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> chart = new AreaChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    private XYChart.Series<Integer, Double> heartRateSeries = new XYChart.Series<>(
            HEART_RATE, randomData(10)
    );
    private XYChart.Series<Integer, Double> cadenceSeries = new XYChart.Series<>(
            PEDALING_RATE, randomData(50)
    );
    private XYChart.Series<Integer, Double> speedSeries = new XYChart.Series<>(
            AVERAGE_SPEED, randomData(100)
    );

    private CheckBox heartRateCheck = new CheckBox(HEART_RATE);
    private CheckBox cadenceCheck = new CheckBox(PEDALING_RATE);
    private CheckBox speedCheck = new CheckBox(AVERAGE_SPEED);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        HBox controls = new HBox(10, heartRateCheck, cadenceCheck, speedCheck);
        addSeriesListener(heartRateCheck.selectedProperty(), heartRateSeries);
        addSeriesListener(cadenceCheck.selectedProperty(), cadenceSeries);
        addSeriesListener(speedCheck.selectedProperty(), speedSeries);
        heartRateCheck.selectedProperty().set(true);
        cadenceCheck.selectedProperty().set(true);
        speedCheck.selectedProperty().set(true);

        chart.setTitle("Cycling");
        VBox layout = new VBox(10, chart, controls);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Integer, Double>> randomData(
            double offset
    ) {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Integer, Double>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int x = 0; x < 225; x++) {
            double y = random.nextDouble() * 30 + offset;
            data.add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, y));
        }

        return data;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void addSeriesListener(BooleanProperty selected, final XYChart.Series series) {
        selected.addListener((observable, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
            if (isSelected) {
                chart.getData().add(series);
            } else {
                chart.getData().remove(series);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution fails when adding/removing series quickly. I guess there is some background work going on so the adding/removing os series is asynchronous... ¿Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: JavaFX is a synchronous framework, so any issue like you describe would be a weird bug and would occur for a different reason.  You could try switching animation off for the charts and see if that works for you.  You can also file bugs at bugreport.java.com if you believe it is a platform bug.

Comment: Yes, I ran some tests and `chart.setAnimated(false);` will work-around the issue.

Comment: I had already tried to switch animations off, but the problem persisted

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate your issue with animation off (jdk8u60).

Comment: I finally solved my problems after carefully debugging my code, you were right @jewelsea